# How to preserve value from promise for use in subsequent code?

Tags: javascript

I'm doing a database query and then processing the data so that it will yield a single numeric value.  That value needs to be used in a subsequent array.

The array definition currently looks like this (below).  The problem is `all_kdm_coverage` is a promise. But what I need to do is extract the numeric value from the promise.

```js
const scrolls = [
    {
        title: "Kadena de Mano",
        link: "./Kdm",
        coverage: all_kdm_coverage
    },
]
```

Here is a larger snippet to provide more context

```js
async function GetCoverage(scroll_path) {
    const apiName = 'foo';
    const path = '/scrolls/' + scroll_path;
    const myInit = {
        headers: {},
        response: false,
    };
    const response = await API.get(apiName, path, myInit)
    console.log('response:',response)
    return response.Items
}

function GetScroll(scroll_name, scroll_array) {
    const scroll_data = scroll_array.find(scroll => scroll.Scroll === scroll_name);
    console.log('scroll_data:',scroll_data)
    return scroll_data
}

let dataGlobal;
const getData = () => (dataGlobal ??= GetCoverage("all"));

const all_kdm_coverage = getData().then(
    (data) => {
        const  kdm_entry = GetScroll("kdm", data)
        const coverage = kdm_entry.Coverage
        console.log('kdm coverage:',coverage)
        return coverage
    }
)

const scrolls = [
    {
        title: "Kadena de Mano",
        link: "./Kdm",
        coverage: all_kdm_coverage
    },
]

// For completeness, here is how the scrolls array gets used 
export const DanzanRyuCollection = () => {
    return (
        <>
            <h1 className="h1_index">Scrolls</h1>
            <Collection
                type="list"
                items={scrolls}
                gap="1.0rem"
                alignItems="center">
                {(item, index) => (
                    <ScrollCard
                        key={index}
                        padding="1rem">
                        <Link href={item.link}>
                            {item.title}
                        </Link>
                        <Rating ratings={[item.coverage]}/>
                    </ScrollCard>
                )}
            </Collection>
        </>
    );
};
```

What's the best way to set the `coverage:` value in `scrolls`?

Update:
Its been suggested to do the following

```js
const scrolls = [
    {
        title: "Kadena de Mano",
        link: "./Kdm",
        coverage: await all_kdm_coverage
    },
]
```

But that causes the following error indicating its experimental and not fully supported

````
Module parse failed: The top-level-await experiment is not enabled (set experiments.topLevelAwait: true to enabled it)
Error: The top-level-await experiment is not enabled (set experiments.topLevelAwait: true to enabled it)
console.error @ client.js:1
window.console.error @ next-dev.js:27
overrideMethod @ react_devtools_backend_compact.js:2367
handleErrors @ hot-dev-client.js:131
processMessage @ hot-dev-client.js:202
eval @ hot-dev-client.js:50
eval @ websocket.js:58
handleMessage @ websocket.js:57```
````

Comment: Have you tried `await all_kdm_coverage` ?

Comment: Thanks, but that's considered a top-level await.  Not supported (IIRC)

Comment: Where in your code are you using the `scrolls` array?

Comment: `Not supported` where? what environment is this javascript running in that has async/await but no top level await?

Comment: @Bergi I'll annotate the example to show `scrolls` use

Comment: @JaromandaX I'll annotate it to show why

Comment: Basically the two options you have are 1) move `scrolls` (and all the code that depends on it) inside the `.then()` callback, or after an `await`, or b) keep the array global but initialise it as empty, asynchronously push the object when coverage is loaded, and if necessary somehow notify the code that uses the array about the modification

Comment: is this nodejs? what version?

Answer (score -1):

To expand the comment of [Bergi](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1048572/bergi)

```
const scrolls = [];
all_kdm_coverage.then(coverage => { 
 scrolls.push({ 
   title: "Kadena de Mano",
   link: "./Kdm", 
   coverage, 
  }) 
})
```